# Need help converting decimals to Binary

Tags: functions, binary

I am struggling figuring out how to turn decimals between {0,1} to binary. I am currently trying to use RealDigits[] and FromDigits[]  For example using:

```
myB = RealDigits[myNum, 2];
myBExp = myB[[2]];
newFormat = 
 ToString@Row[myB[[1, 1 ;; myBExp]]] <> "." <> 
  ToString@Row[myB[[1, myBExp + 1 ;;]]]
```

Gives:

```
1110101110000101000111101011100001010001111010111000.1
```

Which is different when I use BaseForm[]
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works correctly only if `myBExp` is not negative. If it's negative, you will need an additional if statement that takes care of it. For example something like this:

```
myNum = 0.2;

myB = RealDigits[myNum, 2];
myBExp = myB[[2]];
newFormat =
 If[myBExp >= 0,
  ToString@Row[myB[[1, 1 ;; myBExp]]] <> "." <> 
   ToString@Row[myB[[1, myBExp + 1 ;;]]],
  "." <> Table[ToString@0, {-myBExp}] <> ToString@Row[myB[[1]]]
  ]
BaseForm[myNum, 2]
```

[image]